# Output range for continuous control policy network

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, reinforcement-learning

I tried to implement the simple vanilla policy gradient (REINFORCE) in a continuous control problem by adapting [this pytorch implementation](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/reinforcement_learning/reinforce.py) to the continuous case and I stumbled upon the following issue.

Usually, when the action space is **discrete**, the output of the policy network is bounded in `(0,1)^n` by the softmax function which gives the probability that the agent would pick a certain action given the state (input to the network). However, when the action space is **continuous**, for example if we have K action such that each action `ak` has lower and upper bounds `lk` and`uk`, I haven't found a way (empirical or theoretical) to **limit the output of the network** (which is usually the means and the standard deviations of the action probability distribution given the state) using `lk` and `uk`.

From the few trials I made, without constraining the output of the policy network, it was very hard, if not impossible, to learn a good policy, but i might be doing something wrong since i am new to reinforcement learning.

My intuition suggests me to limit the means and the standard deviations output of the policy network using, for example, a sigmoid and then scaling them with the absolute difference between `lk` and `uk`. I'm not quite sure how to do it properly though, considering also that the sampled action could exceed whatever bound you impose on the distribution parameters when using, for example, a gaussian distribution.

Am I missing something? **Are there established ways to limit the output of the policy network for continuous action spaces or there's no need to do that at all?**

I am not sure this is the right place for this question, if not I will be glad if you point to me a better place.